# C++: What are the reasons for choosing a linked list / deque over a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list, deque

In the "lighting tour" of `Stroustrup's` 4th edition of TC++PL, he says:

> I recommend the standard-library vector as the default type for
>   sequences of elements: you need a reason to choose another.

It's clear why one would choose a `set` over a vector based on the `invariant` of a set.

But what about `list` and `deque`? Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge/experience to know when to use those over a vector.

Rather than going down a rabbit hole re-searching `linked-lists` and `deque`'s; which I am going to do when I reach the later chapters.  I was hoping someone can give a brief conceptual outline of when there's a reason to use `linked-list` or a `deque` over a vector?

Comment: Different collections have different time complexities when performing operations like insertion, deletion, in the middle, at the beginning or end, etc.

Comment: Does that mean there's then specific use cases for each one? What would be a use case for fastest insertion? fastest deletion?

Comment: Read  [here](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html) and also do your own tests

Comment: @SamHammamy Linked lists also have pointer stability for data in case of reorganizations.

Comment: This is answered by the "When to NOT use std::vector" answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks! That answer is perfect.  I am going to keep this question around in case it comes up in future searches.